# Using multiple parameters in Forena

Tags: 7, forena

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters from one [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) report to another one.
Currently my link looks like this:

```
reports/aen_multi?startdate={eventdate}&enddate={eventdate}
```

but this does not work ("Invalid or malformed report document").

For links with only one parameter this works:

```
reports/aen_multi?startdate={eventdate}
```

What is the correct way of linking to a report with several parameters?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot more, I came across [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena/issues/2738679) which shows that `&` needs to be encoded as `&amp;`.
So the working link is:

```
 reports/aen_multi?startdate={eventdate}&amp;enddate={eventdate}
```

I'll leave the question up as this might help others.